# Как добавить уровень света блоку Minecraft? Forge Modding 1.20.1

Tags: java, minecraft, forge

Я в Java совсем недавно, поэтому вопросы глупые наверное и поэтому не могу найти ответ на них в интернете, буду рад если вы сможете помочь с этим

Когда пытаюсь добавить lightLevel к блоку, он говорит что нужно добавить аргумент `ToIntFunction`

Когда я вроде бы добавляю этот аргумент

```
public static final RegistryObject<Block> GLOWING_WHITE_CONCRETE = registerBlock("glowing_white_concrete",
            () -> new GlowingBlock(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of().lightLevel(ToIntFunction)));
```

Он просит добавить поле

```
    private static java.util.function.ToIntFunction<BlockState> ToIntFunction;
```

Я добавлю и его, и вот дальше совсем не понимаю чего от меня хотят
Мне банально нужно чтобы блок испускал свет в нужном мне значении от 1 до 15 и всё